# Whati is the best way to use loading image in MVC 5

Tags: image, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, loading

I have a 5 column table and has nearly 10000 records. Also I have my custom loading image as gif. In MVC 5 what is the besat way to use loading image before large data to be shown (in Index.cshtml)?

```
// GET: CUSTOMERS
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.CUSTOMERS.ToList());
}
```

Comment: can you specify your exact need. and please make it more clear

Comment: It all depends on how the data is loaded. If you load the whole table synchronously rendered into the page, the request is probably blocking and you will have huge difficulties to display some loading indicator. If you load the Data asynchronously (e.g. using Ajax) that's a different story. You'd need to show us some of your code.

Comment: I update my questions. In CUSTOMER/Index.cshtml is auto generrated using EntityFramework 6.